# Tkinter stalling the mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a GUI with a graph that updates rather fast and i had it working great. Recently I've added in another component to my experiment that requires Serial communication via RS-232. When i use the `root.after()` method to call my function that reads the data from the Serial device the main loop stalls. So I thought i would try to move it to a different thread to try and avoid that but it doesn't seem like that helped. Then according to the comments i split it up into several different callbacks to avoid a costly while loop. The performance is now better but it still stalls. How do i get this to work without stalling the `root.mainloop()`?

Here is the new code: **EDITED:**

```
def callback_PCreadWrapper():
   print 'Starting thread'
   thread.start_new_thread(callback_PCread1,())

def callback_PCread1():
    global ser, um1, trash, status,delay
    ser.write('e')
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        trash += ser.read(1)
    ser.write('A')
    root.after(500,callback_PCread2)

def callback_PCread2()
    trash=''    
    trash = ser.read(2)
    current_status = ser.read(1)
    if current_status == " ":
        status = 'No alarms'
    elif current_status == "!":
        status = 'Sensor Fail'
    elif current_status == "$":
        status = "Count Alarm"
    else:
        status = current_status
    trash += ser.read(24)
    um1 = ser.read(6)
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        trash += ser.read(1)
    print 'Ending Thread'   
    root.after(10000,callback_PCreadWrapper)

Canvas.bind_all("<End>",callback_end)
root.after(samplePeriod, writeData) # status and 1um are written to a file
root.after(10000, callback_PCreadWrapper)
root.mainloop()
```

if you want to look at all the code [here is the LONG version](https://github.com/pmnick/backwashcode/blob/master/Backwaushomator.py) on github

Comment: Please fix your indentation, currently the serial read loop will give an IndentationError, also make it consistent. Also I'd suggest not reusing the status variable name when performing the serial read, that strikes me as a code smell.

Comment: @shuttle indentation was fixed. Can you please explain what you mean by not reusing the status variable name?

Comment: I'd do something like `current_status = ser.read(1)` then check vs this variable: `if current_status == " ":` then set the global `status` with the appropriate value. Reading into the global variable directly makes the code harder to read and also looks like something that will be able to cause problems. For example it's not *immediately* obvious what `status = status` does.

Comment: I am inexperienced with threads but your threading code does not look right to me.  Since threads did not solve your problem, and introduce the possibility of deadlocks, I would try fixing the problem without them.  `callback_PCRead` has three while loops that hog the cpu (or at least the core) for an indefinite amount of time.  This was OK with MSDOS when the CPU would be idle anyway, but not in an event loop.  I suspect that you need to break this up into 3 or 4 chained callbacks which reschedule either themselves or the next after doing a bit or work or checking readiness.

Comment: @Terry Can you explain this chained callback method your talking about

Comment: Instead of one callback c scheduling itself with root.after(n, c, ...), you have, say, 3.  C1 schedules c2, c2 schedules sets c3, c3 schedule c1, and so on.  Or a 'wait' callback can conditionally schedule itself or the next, depending on whether there is work to be done.  The point is to not block the event loop.

Comment: "Terry I edited my code above to what i think reflects your comment, but it still stalls. is that what you mean? or am i still doing it wrong?